# How to clear the fields and reset the form inside a modal after closing?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form inside a modal with fields that have red borders onload, indicating that the fields are mandatory. When I fill up each field, the red border will disappear. When I close the modal, the fields are cleared out but the red border is no longer visible, meaning the fields are no longer mandatory thus the user can submit the form successfully without filling out the required fields. How do I fix this? Please HELP.

This function did clear the fields but fields are no longer mandatory after.

```
$scope.clearFields = function() {
        $('#orderForm').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
            $(this).find('form').trigger('reset');
        });
    };
```

This is my modal's code.

```
 <div class="form-group col-md-12" ng-class="{'has-error': !hwmodel.length}">
    <label for="hwmodel" class="control-label label-bold">Hardware Brand/Model</label>
    <div>
        <textarea class="form-control" name="hwmodel" id="hwmodel" ng-model="hwmodel" maxlength="500" style="height:65px;"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the red border does not make anything mandatory they are just styles. you have put more code or explain what is responsible for making it mandatory

Comment: How do you determine if a field is required and prevent the user to submit the form? how does the form look like? Please include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I have this line:

<div class="form-group col-md-12" ng-class="{'has-error': !hwmodel.length}">

Comment: can anyone comment their email so I could send the screenshot of my modal? Sorry. I don't really know how to use stackoverflow. Thanks for understanding

Comment: use **document.getElementById("myForm").reset();** or **$("#myForm").reset();** or try this link [https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_validation.asp] for proper validation understanding

Comment: u r mixing bootstrap with angular, why to use events and jquery with Angular, anyway, when u closed the modal, fields are cleared, how r u able to see the fields and borders when the modal is closed

Answer (score 0):

replace it with:

```
 $(this).closest('form').find("input").val("");
```

Comment: I have textarea and sn-record-picker.

Comment: ok so you need to change it to :
$(this).closest('form').find("input[type=textarea]").val(""); 
for text areas. and for sn-record-picker you should read the docs of that plugin.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this way then it will only rest the input field with type text. 
$(this).closest('form').find("input[type=text]").val("");
So there is a better way doing it. If you know all the fields the create a function and put the logic to reset all field's data there one by one if not able to group them. May be you can do it using id's of some field and name of some field. Annd call it before closing the modal. This way is a way better because may be in future you will add more/different types of fields.